# How to speed up Curl connection with proxy?

Tags: php, curl, proxy, php-curl

So i have got this kind of code.

```
if (!file_exists($cache_json) || $ageInSeconds < $_TIME - filemtime($cache_json) || filesize($cache_json) == 0) {
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt_array($ch, [
        CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE       => CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => true,
        CURLOPT_HEADER          => false,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER  => false,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION  => true,
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS       => 2,
        CURLOPT_PROXY           => 'IP:port',
        CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD    => 'User:pass',
        CURLOPT_ENCODING        => 'gzip, deflate',
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT  => 3,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT         => 3,
    ]);
    $contents = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

  $contents && file_put_contents($cache_json, $contents);
}
```

it works BUT realy slow... i aded CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE => CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4 nothing changed... Maybe there is another trick what i coul try?

i aded CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE => CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4 nothing changed. need to speed up curl conection

Comment: What is it that makes you think it's the PHP curl code causing the slowness? There can be many reason a connection is slow. Did you exclude those? Are there ways you can do the same but it works a lot faster? If so, in what way does it differ from your code here?